# JAVA ERROR: execption in thread"main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I am taking an introductory class in programming with Java, so please excuse my ignorance when it comes to programming concepts/terminology. Part of my current assignment is to create a program that computes and display a game character's attack speed at a certain level.

I have this problem that always says:

> Enter the base attack speed:
> Enter the bonus attack speed %:
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
> at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
> at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
> at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
> at Characterattackspeed.main(Characterattackspeed.java:15)

I have the code here :

```
public class Characterattackspeed{

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    double base;
    double bonus;
    double current;
    int level;
    
    System.out.println("Enter the base attack speed: ");
    base = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the bonus attack speed %: ");
    bonus = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the level: ");
    level = in.nextInt();
    
    bonus = bonus / 100;
    current = base * (1 + (bonus * (level - 1)));
    
    System.out.printf("current attack speed is %.3f.", current);
    
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: [Scanner#nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) and [Scanner#nextDouble()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) throw _NoSuchElementException - if the input is exhausted_. Can you specify your input?

Comment: Heya mate. For cases such as this where there's a error thrown, it helps us a lot if you put the entire error log into your question and wrap it via the code `{}` button.

Comment: As for the error, per maloomeister's comment... You're likely running into a common error that can happen with Scanner when using `.nextInt()` and `.nextDouble()`. What happens is these methods don't clear the entire input, they only target the first Int or Double they find. This means some left over data can interfere. I recommend using `.nextLine()` to grab all the data and then try converting it to a Int/Double via the `Integer.parseInt(input);` and `Double.parseDouble(input);` methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

with the correct imports this runs (tested and running ok here):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Characterattackspeed {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double base;
        double bonus;
        double current;
        int level;

        out.println("Enter the base attack speed: ");
        base = in.nextDouble();
        out.println("Enter the bonus attack speed %: ");
        bonus = in.nextDouble();
        out.println("Enter the level: ");
        level = in.nextInt();

        bonus = bonus / 100;
        current = base * (1 + (bonus * (level - 1)));

        out.printf("current attack speed is %.3f.", current);


    }

}
```

Example output:

```
Enter the base attack speed: 
12
Enter the bonus attack speed %: 
12
Enter the level: 
1
current attack speed is 12,000.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

You might want to enhance the code to use methods and objects, but that's not the original question.